# How to Make DataTables Load AJAX Data From Django as Needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, datatables

I am attempting to serialize a Django queryset, return the results to a URL, and point a DataTable to the resulting URL. This potential solution arose to address the issue of slow performance when loading thousands of rows from Django into a DataTable through the DOM.

I have a view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core import serializers
def json_ouput(request):
    objects= MyModel.objects.all()
    json = serializers.serialize('json', objects)
    return HttpResponse(json, content_type='application/json')
```

The view connects to this URL:

```
url(r'^home/json_ouput/$', views.json_ouput, name='json_ouput_url',),
```

My temlate points to this URL as the AJAX source for the DataTable:

```
<table id="example">
     <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th></th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
</table>


<script defer type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "processing": true,
      "ajax": {
        "processing": true,
        "url": "{% url 'json_output_url' %}",
        "dataSrc":''
      },
      "scrollY":        800,
      "deferRender":    true,
      "scroller":       true,
      "columns": [
        { "data": "fields.description" },
        { "data": "pk" }
                  ]
                });
              });
</script>
```

Results are displayed after about 40 seconds for 9,000 rows. This is the same performance that occurs with loading the data through the DOM (not serialized into JSON) and without DataTables [Scroller](https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/). My understanding, was that Scroller would not load all data, but it appears to load all data at once (i.e. all 9,000 rows are in the DOM before data is shown).

How do I get DataTables to load the data piecemeal as the table is scrolled? Or is there something I can do on the Django side to paginate the data first?

Comment: simply use django-datatables-view for better performance and easy implemenation.Reference link: https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/

Comment: thanks - I've started implementing that, and it works great for normal fields. Do you have any insight into how to incorporate many-to-many fields, as well as the `str` representations of foreign key fields? the example documentation is for an older version with different syntax.